# Generic function to get the net mask width of a std::net::Ipv6Addr or a std::net::Ipv4Addr

Tags: rust

This code works, but the `TODO` says it all: the functions are essentially identical.

I could use a declarative macro, however I'd prefer to use a generic. Problematically `Ipv6Addr` and `Ipv4Addr` share no traits that provide access to the all important `octets` method.

How can I overcome this?

```rust
//TODO: these two function are identical
fn v6_netmask_width(netmask: network_interface::Netmask<Ipv6Addr>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(netmask) = netmask {
        netmask.octets().iter().map(|x| *x as i32).sum()
    } else {
        0
    }
}

fn v4_netmask_width(netmask: network_interface::Netmask<Ipv4Addr>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(netmask) = netmask {
        netmask.octets().iter().map(|x| *x as i32).sum()
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, but you are trying do do generic code to avoid the repetition of a 5 line function. It is likely that the boilerplate of any macro or generic implementation will be longer.

But if what you want is to avoid the repetition of the logic itself, an easy solution is to do the call to `octets()` locally and then manage the resulting byte array generically:

```
fn xx_netmask_width<const SZ: usize>(netmask: Option<[u8; SZ]>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(netmask) = netmask {
        netmask.iter().map(|x| *x as i32).sum()
    } else {
        0
    }
}

fn v6_netmask_width(netmask: Option<Ipv6Addr>) -> i32 {
    xx_netmask_width(netmask.as_ref().map(Ipv6Addr::octets))
}

fn v4_netmask_width(netmask: Option<Ipv4Addr>) -> i32 {
    xx_netmask_width(netmask.as_ref().map(Ipv4Addr::octets))
}
```

Naturally, you could write a trait `Octetable` and skip one-liners. I don't think it is worth it, unless the actual logic is a bit longer. But just for show:

```
trait Octetable {
    type Output: IntoIterator<Item=u8>;
    fn octets(&self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl Octetable for Ipv6Addr {
    type Output = [u8; 16];
    fn octets(&self) -> [u8; 16] {
        Ipv6Addr::octets(self)
    }
}

impl Octetable for Ipv4Addr {
    type Output = [u8; 4];
    fn octets(&self) -> [u8; 4] {
        Ipv4Addr::octets(self)
    }
}

fn netmask_width(netmask: Option<impl Octetable>) -> i32 {
    if let Some(netmask) = netmask {
        netmask.octets().into_iter().map(|x| x as i32).sum()
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```